# Singleton test not working when var is instantiated with *

Tags: go

I'm following the Singleton design pattern as described in this book (https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Go-Design-Patterns/blob/master/Chapter02/main.go) and I have this code in file "singleton2.go":

```
package singleton2

type Singleton interface {
  AddOne() int
}

type singleton struct {
  count int
}

//var instance = &singleton{}
var instance *singleton

func GetInstance() *singleton {
  if instance == nil {
    return new(singleton)
  }
  return instance
}

func (s *singleton) AddOne() int {
  s.count++
  return s.count
}
```

Then I have this test file (singleton2_test.go):

```
package singleton2

import "testing"

func TestGetInstance(t *testing.T) {
  counter1 := GetInstance()
  if counter1 == nil {
    t.Fatal("expected pointer to Singleton after calling GetInstance(), not nil")
  }

  expectedCounter := counter1

  currentCount := counter1.AddOne()
  if currentCount != 1 {
    t.Errorf("After calling for the first time to count, the counter must be 1 but it is %d", currentCount)
  }

  counter2 := GetInstance()
  if counter2 != expectedCounter {
    t.Errorf("Expected same instance in counter2 but it got a different instance.")
    t.Logf("Got %v, want %v", counter2, expectedCounter)
  }

  currentCount = counter2.AddOne()
  if currentCount != 2 {
    t.Errorf("After calling AddOne() using second counter, the count must be 2, but it was %d", currentCount)
  }

}
```

The problem is that tests always fail:

```
--- FAIL: TestGetInstance (0.00s)
    singleton2_test.go:20: Expected same instance in counter2 but it got a different instance.
    singleton2_test.go:21: Got &{0}, want &{1}
    singleton2_test.go:26: After calling AddOne() using second counter, the count must be 2, but it was 1
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/d3c3/design_patterns/singleton/singleton2    0.029s
```

Interestingly, if I change this line `var instance *singleton` to this line `var instance = &singleton{}` tests pass !?  Why is that? IMO, it should work also with "var instance *singleton"

Can anyone explain this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the logic of your code and it's apparent where the problem is.

When you declare, but do not initialize the singleton (`var instance *singleton`) then `instance` is `nil`. Calling `GetInstance` evaluates `instance == nil` as true and returns a new `*singleton` every time it is called. That is why `counter2` will never equal `expectedCounter` - each call to `GetInstance` is returning a new counter instance.

When you initialize the singleton instance (`var instance = &singleton{}`) then calls to `GetInstance` will return that singleton instance since it is not `nil`.

I imagine you'd want to modify `GetInstance` to something like this:

```
func GetInstance() *singleton {
    if instance == nil {
        instance = new(singleton)
    }
    return instance
}
```

**EDIT**

Although you didn't mention that you need this singleton to be thread-safe, user [colminator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218512/colminator) correctly points out that instantiating a singleton this way can cause multiple go-routines to instantiate their own instance of the singleton, defeating the purpose of having one. Given how prolific concurrency is in Golang it's probably helpful to learn more! [Check out the link he posted here](http://marcio.io/2015/07/singleton-pattern-in-go/).

Comment: Your suggested sutuon is ***not*** go-routine safe. For a full explanation why see: http://marcio.io/2015/07/singleton-pattern-in-go/  TL;DR use sync.Once.Do() for singleton creation.

Comment: Clear. Thanks a lot for detailed explanation.